# Troubleshooting Ubuntu 20.10 freezing except for the mouse

Tags: mouse, dell, 20.10, gdm

I know there are a lot of questions online asking about this topic but most of them look for quick fixes and while they do usually work I am looking for a deeper fix that would prevent this problem from happening to begin with.  So here is the gist, I am working on something that really shouldn't take a lot of resources, and looking at the system monitor CPU doesn't get above 20% and memory doesn't go up past 50%.  Then, suddenly my window freezes, but the mouse still moves.  I have a Dell Inspiron 13-5378 running Ubuntu 20.10 with 8 Gigs of RAM and an Intel i7-7500U @ 2.7GHz and this is what `journalclt` looks like:

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-04-13 06:07:58 PDT, end at Mon 2021-04-19 09:19:44 PDT. --
Apr 13 06:07:58 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-keyring-daemon[2469]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
Apr 13 06:08:46 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 snap-store[3026]: not handling error download-failed for action refresh: W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dow>
                                                         E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
                                                         W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
                                                         W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
                                                         E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
                                                         W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
                                                         W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Apr 13 06:08:50 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 dbus-daemon[2463]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gtk/Notifications" interface="org.gtk.Notifications" member="AddNotificati>
Apr 13 06:10:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Starting Kite Updater...
Apr 13 06:10:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: kite-updater.service: Succeeded.
Apr 13 06:10:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Finished Kite Updater.
Apr 13 06:11:39 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 pkexec[269277]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Apr 13 06:26:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Starting Kite Updater...
Apr 13 06:26:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: kite-updater.service: Succeeded.
Apr 13 06:26:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Finished Kite Updater.
Apr 13 06:42:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Starting Kite Updater...
Apr 13 06:42:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: kite-updater.service: Succeeded.
Apr 13 06:42:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Finished Kite Updater.
Apr 13 06:58:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Starting Kite Updater...
Apr 13 06:58:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: kite-updater.service: Succeeded.
Apr 13 06:58:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Finished Kite Updater.
Apr 13 07:07:58 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-keyring-daemon[2469]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
Apr 13 07:14:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Starting Kite Updater...
Apr 13 07:14:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: kite-updater.service: Succeeded.
Apr 13 07:14:52 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 systemd[2451]: Finished Kite Updater.
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Indy Fuel (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event27)
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Indy Fuel (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Indy Fuel (AVRCP)'
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event27 13:91 fd 93 paused 0
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Indy Fuel (AVRCP): always reports core events
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event27"
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) event27 - Indy Fuel (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) event27 - Indy Fuel (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) event27 - Indy Fuel (AVRCP): device removed
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input57/event27"
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Indy Fuel (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 25)
Apr 13 07:18:59 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,us"
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" "dvorak,"
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp_led:scroll"
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) event27 - Indy Fuel (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2551]: (II) event27 - Indy Fuel (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Apr 13 07:19:00 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 gnome-shell[54302]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
```

I don't know what other information would be useful in a deep troubleshoot but I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: SSD or HDD? I'm sure you know where this is going...

Comment: @ChanganAuto SSD.